# WinRT: ListView SelectedItem updating, but not highlighted

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, winrt-xaml

I have the following code in a Windows metro app, I confirmed that SelectedPerson is updating and is properly bound, but the item will not be highlighted unless you click on it.

```
<ListView x:Name="HeaderFlyoutListView" Padding="0" Margin="0" 
 ItemsSource="{Binding People}" SelectionMode="Single" 
 SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPerson, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
```

Comment: I did set up an item template, I didn't post it because I doubt it has any relevance considering that if you do click on the item, it does highlight. The problem is when the SelectedPerson property is updated elsewhere, the ListView doesn't highlight that person.

Answer (score 0):

did you setup your item template?
What you can do is - Define a `SolidColorBrush` Property and bind this property to your Item Grid. and then when you select an item, make sure that property change too

Comment: I did set up an item template, I didn't post it because I doubt it has any relevance considering that if you do click on the item, it does highlight. The problem is when the SelectedPerson property is updated elsewhere, the ListView doesn't highlight that person.